# Error Whle compiling software. "Unable to find the 'dump_syms'"

Tags: compiling, source, atom-editor

I am trying to compile the *Atom text editor* from source, and I'm stuck at the following error. I think it's related to java. I've looked online for information on this particular error, but I haven't found any clear answers, so I decided to post here.

It looks like its trying to dump "symbols" in `/home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/out/symbols` but gets hung up because it can't find the "dump_syms" it's trying to reference.

```
Generating API docs at /home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/docs/output/atom-api.json
Dumping symbols in /home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/out/symbols
Unable to find the "dump_syms"
Error: Unable to find the "dump_syms" *this message was repeated 22 times*
at /home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/script/lib/dump-symbols.js:26:15
at Object.module.exports.dumpSymbol (/home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/script/node_modules/minidump/lib/minidump.js:65:5)
at /home/jgsatellite/Programs/atom/script/lib/dump-symbols.js:23:14
...
```

There's a longer list of "at" that I didn't include to save time.
Is it trying to pull the symbols from the paths listed after "at" and put them in the */out/symbols folder?

They all appear to be javascript files.

Are the "dump_syms" lines of code in the file? Is *dump-symbols.js:23:14 referencing line 23 and 14 in the file? I'm guessing this is where the conflict is arising.

I checked to see if there's a file called *out/symbols in the out folder, but its not there. Is the compiler trying to generate a file called symbols from these other processes and failing to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The message `Unable to find the "dump_syms"` appears when `dump_syms` command does not exist.

Try to install [google-breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad)

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/depot_tools
mkdir breakpad && cd breakpad
fetch breakpad
cd src
./configure && make
sudo make install
```

and create a symbolic link for the `minidump` module

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/dump_syms atom/script/node_modules/minidump/bin/dump_syms
```